# How to make dynamic localization with sencha architect 4 and extjs 6?

Tags: javascript, extjs, localization, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd

I'm trying to make a dynamic localization in sencha architect, but when I modify app.json file, after build it is overwritten by sencha architect and I can't find solution for this, or example how to do dynamic localization. I want user to select language in combobox and application reload with corresponding language.

Comment: Why would you want to modify app.json?

Comment: I was following this tutorial : https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/core_concepts/localization.html
and wanted to add this line :  "overrides": "${app.dir}/overrides,${app.dir}/locale/${app.locale}",

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide in app.json(architect generated)
1) "requires": [
      "ext-locale"
   ]
2) "locale": "no_NB"
build application by SA build web app(test/production)
I already achieved localization in my application.